# Display coded value domains instead of descriptions in attribute window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, fields-attributes, domains

Is it possible to display coded value domains instead of descriptions in attribute window in ArcMap?

I know [this article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/43215) shows how it can be done for the Attribute Table, but what about the [Attribute Window](http://www.esri.ca/sites/default/files/imagemanager/Tutorials/rshp9.png)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to disable a coded value domain in the Attribute window used for editing and there is an existing [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000by46AAA) to do what you are asking so I think this reinforces that it is not currently possible:

> It would be nice if the Attribute Window would follow the same
>   appearance rules as set in the attribute table regarding viewing coded
>   value domain and subtype descriptions.

However, if you are using a File Geodatabase, which I will assume because you do not specify otherwise, then you can effectively disable a domain by removing it from the field temporarily:

1. stop editing and go to the Properties of the feature class with the domain you would like to "disable"
2. click on the Fields tab
3. click on the field you wish to "disable" the domain of
4. set the domain back to the "blank" option

The domain still exists in the file geodatabase.  You have just dissociated it temporarily from the particular field for which you want to see codes rather than descriptions.  It can be easily re-associated using the same steps.

[image]